# Dropping the first column in the downloaded file within shiny app: downloadHandler problem

Tags: r, shiny

Using the below code, the downloadHandler nicely downloads my data of interest (linedata_()) and saves it as a CSV file. I would like the first column to be dropped in the downloaded file.

```
    output$downloadData_ <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("Older_Pop_Sel", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep = ".")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(linedata_(), file, row.names = T)
    }
  )
```

Comment: Does `linedata_()[-1]` work ?

Comment: It perfectly worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can ignore the first column using `[-1]` while writing the csv.

```
output$downloadData_ <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() {
        paste("Older_Pop_Sel", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep = ".")
      },
      content = function(file) {
        write.csv(linedata_()[-1], file, row.names = T)
      }
)
```